# How to use voltage follower after BJT amplifier in LT SPICE

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, bjt, buffer, unity-gain

Hello in a circuit I'm trying to create, a voltage follower is placed at the output of a BJT amplifier in order to create a buffer from the rest of the circuit. When I do this with the "ideal op-amp" provided by lt-spice, it works as expected. However, when I attempt to use an actual model I don't get the expected output (simply something close to a gain of 1).

I've attempted this with several models including the LM324 and the ADA4860. I'm sure I could be missing something on their spec sheets that are causing them to not work but I've tried changing different things (I.e. voltage rails) with no success. Here is the circuit with the LM324:
[image]

I've read that it was necessary to have R2 to give the amp a DC path to the ground. I've tried R2 on a full range of values. I've also read that the coupling capacitor might give it problems, I've attempted to remove it but nothing changed (I do need to filter out the DC bias from the amplifier though). I've tried different frequencies on V4 as well (as low as 1kHz).

I'm not quite sure what else I could do so if there are any suggestions I would appreciate hearing them.

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? I suspect that you have a large DC offset on your output due to the large bias resistor (R2) and the input bias current of the opamp. What does the simulation say about the DC offset on the opamp input and output? You may want to add the output waveforms to your post.

Comment: How close to unity gain do you get? With any amplifier there is a reduction in gain as frequency increases. The LM324 has a GBW of about 1 MHz and so, when configured as a buffer, the gain will be down to 0.707 of its low frequency value at about 1 MHz. The rate of gain roll off is low at low frequency but increases as frequency increases. At 40kHz I would expect to see a small gain reduction below unity.

Comment: The transistor is biased completely wrong so that it is saturated and it rectifies an input signal. The LM324 has an output that produces 1/10th the maximum current of the transistor then the opamp is not a buffer.

Comment: @qrk Well there's no gain at all. The DC offset is rather high, around 6v. I've adjusted the bias resistor to small values (it's only there because I read in another forum it's needed there.

Comment: What voltage is Vcc?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Vcc is at +9v.

Answer (score 2):

> I've read that it was necessary to have R2 to give the amp a DC path
> to the ground.

Correct. The op amp's input needs to source current (~45 nA on the LM324) to bias its input transistor. The resistor value must be low enough to sink this current without excessive voltage drop, because it raises the input voltage. 1 MΩ x 45 nA = 45 mV, which is probably acceptable.

R2 could be made lower, but C4 and R2 form a [high pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#First-order_continuous-time_implementation) with a cutoff frequency of \$ \frac{1}{2\pi RC} \$, so if the value of R2 is too low it will reduce output level at the signal frequency. With 25 nF and 1 MΩ the cutoff frequency is ~6 Hz, which is plenty low enough for audio frequencies. With 1 kΩ it would be ~6 kHz, which might be a problem.

This high pass filtering effect also applies to C3 and R5 || R6. With the values you are using the cutoff frequency of these components is ~84 kHz, so the input signal is already being attenuated by ~7.4 dB at 40 kHz. At lower frequencies it will be worse.

> I've tried different frequencies on V4 as well (as low as 1kHz).

At 1 kHz the signal would be attenuated by ~38.5 dB. To pass audio frequencies without significant attenuation C4 should be made much larger, eg. 100 μF.

This probably explains why reducing the input frequency did not fix your problem. Or to be more precise, it replaced one problem with another.

The next issue is that Q1's input bias voltage is too high, causing it to saturate and clip the lower half of the waveform when the input amplitude exceeds ~0.25 V. Assuming Vcc = +9 V, this can be fixed by increasing R5 to 470 Ω, which should set the quiescent Collector voltage to ~4.6 V and produce ~5.5 Vpp output with low distortion from an input amplitude of 0.5 V peak.

However this reveals another problem - the LM324's [slew rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate) -  which limits the maximum output swing at high frequency. At 40 kHz it is barely able to reach peak amplitude when V4 is 0.5 V, and turns the sine wave into a triangle wave. At audio frequencies this isn't a problem because the slew rate is fast enough to follow the input closely.

Comment: thanks for your reply, and for the explanation on the filtering parts. I'm not using this part of the circuit for audio, just transforming a received signal from an ultrasonic sensor to DC, so I think that's why I'm not running into a lot of those aforementioned problems. Though I'm thinking it's possible that this might change in the actual circuit. I'm going to be building it soon, but do you know if this slew rate problem would cause any further issues in the actual circuit? I'm thinking the triangle wave can still be rectified (not sure how much Spice takes into account Slew)

Comment: Yes, the triangle wave can be rectified. The main effect of slew rate is that it limits the maximum amplitude of the signal. If that is problem then perhaps you could use a faster op amp, or a different method of buffering the signal. In your circuit the output impedance of the transistor stage is 50 ohms, which might be low enough that it doesn't need any buffering.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out as far as the simulation goes. When I was testing with the universal op-amp I simply placed it to the side but left the net on the Amp out attached. With this detached, we can see it works as expected (or at least good enough for what I'm trying to do with it).

[image]

There is a lot of distortion on the bottom of the wave. Not sure what it's from but it doesn't seem to be much of a problem since I'm rectifying it anyway (The pink line is rectified AmpOut).

Comment: Hi, I see you have written an answer to your own question. If you have received as much help as you need (which writing an answer to your own question implies on Stack Exchange) then please consider ["accepting" the answer which helped you the most](/help/someone-answers) (i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer, to turn it green) to effectively close the topic. However, if you still want further replies, then this isn't an *answer* but an *update* instead & should be edited into the question, then deleted as an answer (because if you want more help, then it isn't an *answer*). Thanks.